# What does using ::fun mean when fun is a function?

Tags: c++

```
void fun(){
    std::cout << "hello" << std::endl;
}
namespace enc{
    using ::fun;
}
```

This code above gives no error. I want to understand what's going on here.

What does `using ::fun;` mean?

Comment: `::` is the global namespace resolution operator.
It means that **if** you have a function `fun()` in namespace `enc`, you are telling the compiler that you actually want to use the global `fun()`

Comment: @Raildex: In this case "use the global `fun()`" has two meanings. Also don't answer in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Breaking this down we have:

- `void fun()` is a function that does not return a value (essentially nothing).
- `::` is a *scope resolution operator*. For example, `cout` and `cin` are *defined* in the `std` namespace. To *qualify* their names without using the *using declaration* we have to *qualify* them with `std::cout` and `std::cin`

**To answer the main question, however:**

- `using ::fun;` is called a *using declaration*. A *using declaration* means that you can introduces namespace members into other namespaces, etc. This means that `fun` will now be visible as `::enc::fun;`

For example:

```
void fun() {
    std::cout << "hello" << std::endl;
}
namespace enc {
    using ::fun;
}
void Reallyfun()
{
    enc::fun(); // Which calls ::fun
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`using` a synonymous declaration introduces a name from one declarative region into another. In this case, the name `fun` is introduced into the namespace `::enc` and it is synonymous with `::fun`.